# Trying to get a json response from API web to Android with android-async-http lib

Tags: android, json, api, android-async-http

I've been working with android-async-http (http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) lib with android but for some reason I can't catch the response from server, I know that the server receive and do the things that should do, but I can't get the response for no reason.

Here is the method that calls the API:

```
public User registUser(String mail, String pass) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    final User user = new User();
    user.setToken("enter");

    String bodyAsJson = "{\"user\":{\"email\":\""+mail+"\",\"password\":\""+pass+"\"}}";

    StringEntity entity  = new StringEntity(bodyAsJson);
    Header[] headers = {
            new BasicHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
    };

    client.post(this.context, "http://104.131.189.224/api/user", headers , entity, "application/json",  new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject json) {
            try {
                json = json.getJSONObject("user");
                user.setId(json.getInt("id"));
                user.setEmail(json.getString("email"));
                user.setPassword("123456");
                user.setToken(json.getString("auth_token"));
            } catch ( JSONException e) {
                user.setToken("not json");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                user.setToken("error ");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
            user.setToken("comes json array");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
            user.setToken(responseString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            user.setToken("error");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
            user.setToken("nothing");
        }
    });

    return user;
}
```

when I call the method, the user.getToken shows only the "enter" that I put in the beginin, that means, never entered in the onSuccess, onFailure, or onRetry methods.

but I know that the server receive my request because the server log shows:
(example: email: carlos@prueba.com, pass: prueba)

```
"=>"carlos@prueba.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}                              
    D, [2015-03-17T05:15:27.660562 #28450] DEBUG -- :    (0.8ms)  BEGIN
    D, [2015-03-17T05:15:27.671126 #28450] DEBUG -- :   User Exists (2.6ms)  SELECT
    1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'carlos@prueba.com' LIMIT
    1
    D, [2015-03-17T05:15:27.677448 #28450] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO `us
    ers` (`email`, `encrypted_password`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('carlos
    @prueba.com', '$2a$10$Dg358IzoaG5KVJ8ZJTeViev2v5B9CAnAqIYI1Zd4EIFC.0Mh.nMU6', '2
    015-03-17 05:15:27.672898', '2015-03-17 05:15:27.672898')                       
    D, [2015-03-17T05:15:27.681514 #28450] DEBUG -- :    (2.0ms)  COMMIT
    D, [2015-03-17T05:15:27.684634 #28450] DEBUG -- :   User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT
    1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`auth_token` = '6aff3b4162cfcf3062a6db12a1c
    ee2bc' LIMIT 1                                                                  
    D, [2015-03-17T05:15:27.685582 #28450] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
    D, [2015-03-17T05:15:27.690901 #28450] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.8ms)  UPDATE `users`
    SET `auth_token` = '6aff3b4162cfcf3062a6db12a1cee2bc', `updated_at` = '2015-03-1
    7 05:15:27.687516' WHERE `users`.`id` = 11                                      
    D, [2015-03-17T05:15:27.693809 #28450] DEBUG -- :    (1.8ms)  COMMIT
    I, [2015-03-17T05:15:27.698987 #28450]  INFO -- :   Rendered api/users/_user.jso
    n.jbuilder (0.3ms)
    I, [2015-03-17T05:15:27.700292 #28450]  INFO -- :   Rendered api/users/create.js
    on.jbuilder (3.2ms)
    I, [2015-03-17T05:15:27.701395 #28450]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 223ms (Vie
            ws: 6.3ms | ActiveRecord: 10.0ms)
```

the server should response a json in the format:

```
{"user":{"id":3,"email":"carlos@prueba.com","auth_token":"dc45800fddee07cf9b300d2765283cb2"}}
```

Comment: Provide code from server side.

Comment: i dont have the code from the server side, but let me ask if i can get it
I think the server side code its the problem, i gonna ask for it
But if you read the log, the server response with a 200 code, so why never enter on some onSuccess method in my code?

Comment: To clarify your error, I recommend you to try (1) `AsyncHttpResponseHandler` instead JsonHttpResponseHandler. it's more primitive to check server response. (2) use Fiddler to see actual http communication. it's superb tool to debug http communication.

Comment: the same, never entered in onScucess or whathetever method

Answer (score 0):

Most tutorials are outdated and try to use the apache library however I did find a working one.

While trying to manipulate a Team Treehouse Tutorial ( https://teamtreehouse.com/library/build-a-weather-app/ ) to work for an event finder api instead of their weather api, I ran into the same problem.

They use the OkHttp library

1. compile the OkHttp library into your `build.gradle` file under Module:app

`compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'`

this is the most recent version as of 7/9/15

2. visit the api url to see if you are indeed retrieving the data and that it is in the correct format. For me I was using Eventful.com and finding events in my area. 
   ( https://api.eventful.com/json/events/search?l=arizona&within=15&units=miles&app_key= ) where my app key would go after the "=" at the end of the url.

at this point everything was working great, now I needed to add the OkHttp code to download the json data

3. add internet permissions to your manifest

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.thestephenmiller.myApp" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    </manifest>`

4. Open the class or activity where the request will be made and add the following code.

`String eventfulUrl = "https://api.eventful.com/json/events/search?l=arizona&within=15&units=miles&app_key="+apiKey;
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(eventfulUrl)
                .build();`

and make the call

```
` 
Call call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
            try {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.v(TAG, response.body().string());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception Caught: ", e);
            }
        }
    });
```

all of which was added to `onCreate()`

this line
`Log.v(TAG, response.body().string());`
is what outputs the response to the log and is in the if statement where you can deal with the data.

**The code will not get the response if** the url does not start with "http://" or "https://" however the app will still run error free